# Passing 2 variables from 2 different queries into the same foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

*So I have this foreach loop that looks like this:*

Well, I need to pass into the same foreach loop another variable that unfortunately I can't get it through the getCategories() function;
So I have **another function** with **another variable**, that is passed through this template by a controller from a class function, is there a way I can use another variable into the same foreach? **e.i**:
    **Example:**

```
$template->countries=$className->functionFromClass();//returns =something;
//getCategories() returns=thing;
```

how do I use **countries** variable in the same foreach bellow?
The template:

```
 <!--how do I add $countries variable in this foreach?-->
 <?php foreach(getCategories() as $category && $countries as $country) : ?>//this is not working 
 <?php echo $category->name; ?>&<?php echo $country->name;?>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

The result that I am looking for:
**thing&something**

I've made research and there are indeed questions and responses about foreach but with arrays,**I don't have arrays here, my variables are returned as a single word and they come from 2 different tables**, can someone help me in this problem?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to figure out what you're trying to do, to be honest. What is the problem in the code that you've provided? Is your `$country` in some way linked to the category? Because if it's not, why can't you just populate it before the loop and use it inside it?

Comment: It's not related, $country is a result from a query within a class that is passed through a template, $category is a result of a query but from a different php file, the tables are not related!

Comment: Then I fail to see what the problem is. Why can't you initialise `$country` outside the loop?

Comment: If there's any errors in your query(s) and/or PHP, you should check for them, if you're not doing so already. You using Wordpress here?

Comment: Because as it's written, $country is passed to the template, because in my controller I have some conditions... and I suppose I need to use the foreach to be able to catch the resultset right?

Comment: @Fred -ii- no, I am using HTML

Comment: @andrewsi How can I initialise `<?php $country->name;?>`before the foreach loop, and then use it in the foreach loop? I fail to understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php $countries = getCountries(); // function that return countries array ?>
<?php foreach(getCategories() as $i=>$category) : ?> 
<?php $country = isset($countries[$i]) ? $countries[$i] : end($countries); ?>
<?php echo $category->name; ?>&<?php echo $country->name; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: `$countries` has nothing to do with `getCategories()` function, that's why I find it tricky, they are 2 different variables from 2 different queries...

Comment: Just typo, sorry. There should be function that return countries.

Comment: `getCountries()` in my code returns **1 word** not an array, each variable= **1 word**, that's it.

Comment: Posts the last code from your comment to aprove it !